# DB::transaction throw Undefined variable Error Exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Working on Laravel 5 DB::transaction but throwing following error:

> exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: tasks'

**Here is my code:**

```
private function addTasks($tasks, $id) {
  DB::transaction(function() {
    DB::table('task')->whereIn('id', $tasks)->update(array('task_parent_id' => $id));
  });
}
```

**Note: Its working fine without `DB::transaction` function.**

I've checked every line of code but found nothing wrong, please let me know where did wrong?

Comment: Show us your route !

Comment: try `dd($tasks)` before your query is it have data

Comment: Its a private function so I think no roll of route

Comment: I was thinking that the problem is in `tasks` parameter of `addTasks` but it's as @Андрій said in his answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should pass variable `$tasks` to anonymous function:
**Try this**

```
private function addTasks($tasks, $id) {
      DB::transaction(function() use ($tasks, $id) {
        DB::table('task')->whereIn('id', $tasks)->update(array('task_parent_id' => $id));
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
private function addTasks($tasks, $id) {
    DB::transaction(function() use ($tasks, $id) {
        DB::table('task')->whereIn('id',$tasks)->update(array('task_parent_id' => $id));
    });
}
```